# Serial modification of objects in R

Tags: r, oop

I have a number of matrices of the same size:

```
m1.m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2, ncol=2)
m2.m <- matrix(c(5,6,7,8), nrow=2, ncol=2)
...
```

I want to set uniform column and row names to all of them.

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
new_col_names <- c("Col1","Col2")
new_row_names <- c("Row1","Row2")
change_names <- function(m, new_col_names, new_row_names) {
  colnames(m) <- new_col_names
  rownames(m) <- new_row_names
  return(m)
}
m1.m <- change_names(m1.m, new_col_names, new_row_names)
m2.m <- change_names(m2.m, new_col_names, new_row_names)
...
```

Is there a way to make serial modification (overcoming copying of objects while passing to functions)? So far I tried to run a replacement function within `lapply`; however, it does not seem to work that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a list of all your matrices using `mget` and `ls` (and some regex expression according to the names of your matrices) and then modify them all at once using `lapply` and `colnames<-` and `rownames<-` replacement functions. Something among these lines

```
l <- mget(ls(patter = "m\\d+.m"))
lapply(l, function(x) {
                       x <- `colnames<-`(x, new_col_names) 
                       `rownames<-`(x, new_row_names)
                      })
# $m1.m
#      Col1 Col2
# Row1    1    3
# Row2    2    4
# 
# $m2.m
#      Col1 Col2
# Row1    5    7
# Row2    6    8
```

It is generally recommended to keep your objects within a list instead of polluting the global environment, so try not to listen to anyone that will tell you to use `list2env` as next step.